# Google App Script Grouping data in sheet to email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, grouping

I have an action item Google sheet with these columns:

- A - ID - a serial # 1, 2, 3, etc.
- B - Assigned - date the action item was assigned
- C - Product - short text name of the project or area
- D - Action Item - text description of the action item
- E - Owner - who is the item assigned to, this is usually just a name
  like Bob L, or    sometimes multiple people Bob/Ted
- F - Due Date
- G - Status - Pending,  In process, etc.
- H - Last Updated - updated by onEdit script
- I - Last Edited By - updated by onEdit script
- J - Owner Email - vlookup to data range to get email address(s) of
  owner(s)
- K - Last Reminder Sent - date of the last email sent updated by
  script

I'm a total newbie with GAS so I've cobbled together snippets to get the script to send 1 email to the owner for each action item but I want to group the action items by column E (Owner) and send one email.  I know I need a nested loop but I'm not sure how to proceed.
The format of the resulting email would need to be a table of columns A, B, D, F, G (at least).  The current script is below:

## SCRIPT

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  //var numRows = 12;   // Number of rows to process                     *CHANGE AS NEEDED*

  //var numItems = getRowsData(sheet, OpenItems);
   var numItems = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("OpenItems").getValues();


  var numRows = numItems[0]

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11) // must encompass Column K (11) 
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    var row = data[i];
    var actionitemid = row[0];
    var assignedon = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[1]), "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yy");
    var assignedto = row[4];
    var project = row[2];
    var actionitem = row[3];
    var duedate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[5]), "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yy");
    if (duedate == "12/31/69") { // no due date
      var duedate = "TBD - please update!!" ;}
    var status = row[6];
    var emailAddress = row[9];  // Column J = 9 (starts at A=0

    var subject = "Action Item Reminder - Project: " + project;
    var sheetURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
    var body = "A reminder to do the following:\n\n    Project: "+project + "\n        Due: "+duedate+"\nAssigned: "+assignedon+"\n    Owner: "+assignedto+"\n    Status: " + status + "\n\nACTION ITEM: "+actionitemid+"\n=============================\n"+actionitem+"\n=============================\n\nPlease advise if you will not meet the due date ASAP.\n\nAll action items can be found in the Action Item sheet:\n"+sheetURL+"."; 
    var emailSent = row[11];     // Column D = 3


 //   if (oktosend == "Y") {  // Send only for marked rows
    var ok = emailAddress.length

    if ( emailAddress.length > 0) {

// Send email
 //     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body);
 //     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "TEST", body);
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress, 
        cc: "rdeloach@rentpath.com",
        subject: subject, 
        body: body
      });
       // Update EmailSent
           var time = new Date();
           time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm");
           sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 11).setValue(time);  // Use column for EmailSent + 1 here getRange(startRow + i, X)
       // Update oktosend to N
 //          sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue('N');  // Use column for oktosend + 1 here getRange(startRow + i, X)
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } //oktosend<>N
  }
}
```

## OUTPUT/RESULT

> ​Subject: Action Item Reminder - Project: Project X
>
> A reminder to do the following:
>
> Project: Project X
>          Due: 3/1/14
>   Assigned: 02/01/14
>      Owner: Rick D
>      Status: Pending
>
> ACTION ITEM: 1
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   Provide the data requirements for the new database tables on project X.
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Please advise if you will not meet the due date ASAP.
>
> All action items can be found in the Action Item sheet:
>   
>   END OUTPUT

Looking for help on the grouping and producing a table in Gmail.

Comment: Take a look at this [script on github](https://github.com/Jacobvdb/gdg-event-administration/blob/master/gdg/add_gdg.gs), especially the respondToAdd function it shows how to format an e-mail with html markup. So you could use a table as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the table in the body of the message and then send it through the GmailApp service instead of MailApp.

```
var body = '<table><tr><td>col</td><td>val</td></tr></table>';
GmailApp.sendMail('to@example.com', 'subject', '', 
      { cc: 'cc@example.com',
        htmlBody: body 
      });
```